# Converter Dual/Single output

Tags: dc-dc-converter

what is the difference between Dual output converter and single output converter.
we must use each in which application?
what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: the name fully describes the difference. What is the question there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the needs of the powered circuits and on the topology of the converter itself. Single output of course only have one regulation loop but in some case (flybacks, usually) you can have other less-regulated outputs.

Double output converters can be either simply two indipendent control loops in the same package for convenience (there are even 8+ outputs converters, they call them PMUs usually) or optimized dual-phase converter which alternatively pump one output or another.

Except for polyphase switchers the only real difference is price and convenience of use. There are also some EMC issues but these have to be decided case by case (converter synchronization, most of the time)

Answer (score 0):

> what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

One produces two output voltage rails and the other only produces a single output rail so, the "choice" is driven by your target application and, there are no advantages/disadvantages because there is no overlap.

Use the one that is most appropriate to your target application. If your target requires (say) + and - 12 volts then use a dual output converter or, if you have enough PCB area use a single output converter and supplement this with another DC to DC converter capable of a negative output.